# Making a list with the columns names that meet a condition

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe with FALSE and TRUE in each cell... I want to make a list with the names of the columns that have at least one TRUE.

```
 col1 col2 col3 col4  
FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE  
FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE  
FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE
```

I want this output:

[col2, col3, col4]

How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a 'just ask' forum. Please give it a try and come back to edit your question with the code you actually tried.
We will be glad to answer to precise technical question based on your code.
See MRE here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple code does it:

```
colList = []
for col in df.columns:
    if True in df[col].unique():
        colList.append(col)
```

This gives you a `colList` with the names of the columns that have `True` in them.
(Assuming your dataframe is named `df`)

Comment: Do check out the other answer by @Jayvee that doesn't require a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to generate the list of columns:

```
cols=df.columns[(df == True).any()]

print(cols)
```